# How can I add AdSense in Vue 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3, adsense

I am creating an Ionic Vue 3 app.

My approach to showing ads is to check current platform:
If it is running on Android, I use AdMob thanks to AdMob Plus which is working fine.
For web, I want to use AdSense, and tried using vue-google-adsense, but it is only compatible with Vue 2.

How can I implement AdSense in Vue 3?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? im running into the same issue.